# How do i list all roles in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to list all roles to add to all of them a permission, how do i list all roles?

```
for member in server.members:
    for role in member.roles:
        print(role.id)
```

I saw this code on reddit but it dosent print anything, so how do i list all roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends where you're doing it, but in a command it would look like:

```py
@bot.command()
async def roles(ctx):
    print(", ".join([str(r.id) for r in ctx.guild.roles]))
```

And if you need to get the guild (if you're using an event and the necessary obj isn't avialable), you can use:

```py
guild = bot.get_guild(ID_HERE)
print(", ".join([str(r.id) for r in guild.roles]))
```

**Post-edit:**

```py
@bot.command()
async def rmvroles(ctx):
    role_ids = [112233445566778899, 224466881133557799 # etc...
    for role in [r for r in ctx.guild.roles if r.id in role_ids]:
        try:
            await role.delete()
        except:
            await ctx.send(f"Couldn't delete {role.name} ({role.id}).")
    await ctx.send("Deleted roles.")
```

---

**References:**

- [List comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)
- [`Client.get_guild()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild)
- [`Guild.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.roles)
- [`Role.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.id)
- [`Role.delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.delete)

Comment: ```print(", ".join([r.id for r in ctx.guild.roles]))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found```

Comment: @crashback Sorry, I always forget about that haha, see edited answer ^

Answer (score 0):

Hey still wondering on this post, how would I be able to sort that in order? Top -> Bottom of the discord roles, as for me it goes from the lowest role to the highest role, maybe i'm missing something or not understanding but would love some assistance!

**After-edit:**

```
@client.hybrid_command()
async def roles(ctx: commands.Context):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Roles [{len(ctx.guild.roles)}]", description="\n ".join([str(r.mention) for r in sorted(ctx.guild.roles, reverse=True)]))
    
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Found out that this works well we can just reverse the ctx.guild.roles and how it posts and it's perfect, if y'all would like to use it!